# Playing Videos/media files in c#

Tags: flv, mpeg

I am working on one of the media project (windows application). In this the flv, avi and mpeg are the main file types which i have to play in application. I can use wmpLib, but it will not play flv files. So what procedure should i follow and what tools or libraries should i use.Is there any free opensource libraries to do media work. Thanks in advance

Comment: Just for playback purposes only?

Answer (score 0):

Typically DirectShow is used to play AVI and MPEG. I have no idea on FLV files.